# Reusable std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to make `std::shared_ptr` not to delete an object, but move it to a list?

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>

struct QObject { double socialDistance; };

int main()
{
    std::list<QObject *> free_objects;
    std::list<QObject *> used_objects;
    
    QObject* p_object = new QObject{10};
    
    free_objects.push_back(p_object);
    
    {
        std::shared_ptr<QObject> p(p_object);
    }
    
    //At this point p_object is moved from free_objects to used_objects,
    //so I reuse the object later.

    return 0;
}
```

If yes, is it possible to reuse not only the objects but also the control block to avoid memory reallocation?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to use `std::shared_ptr` to do this, but it doesn't seem like it would be hard to create your own clone that would do what you need.

Comment: You can do almost anything with a custom deleter.

Comment: @MarkRansom then I need to clone std::weak_ptr too

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can I reuse control block?

Comment: You have no control over how the standard library manages the control block. You could in theory write a custom allocator for `shared_ptr` that hangs on to the raw memory of the block. But to me it seems like more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Cloning `std::weak_ptr` as well doesn't seem like a show-stopper if you need it.  I would argue that doing your own smart pointer implementation would be a good introduction to template based programming.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica if you could expand that into an answer, it would be perfect.  Sounds like something that would be useful to a few people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make std::shared_ptr not to delete an object, but move it to a list?

You might use custom deleter for that:

```
std::shared_ptr<QObject> p(p_object, [&](QObject* p){
                used_objects.push_back(p);
                auto it = std::find(free_objects.begin(), free_objects.end(), p);
                if (it != free_objects.end()) free_objects.erase(it);
            });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baf016d9889acd07)